# How does the compiler know about exceptions to be thrown before execution?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
class ex3
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       myfun();
    }

    static void myfun()
    {
        try
        {
           FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("file.ytxt");
           System.out.println("my fun");
        }

        catch(Exception e) //Line 1
        {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException e) //Line 2
        {
           System.out.println("File Not Found Caught");
        }
    }
}
```

I have created two exceptions handler code (one generic and another specific in Line 1 and Line 2).

My compiler is complaining

```
ex3.java:24: error: exception FileNotFoundException has already been caught
                catch(FileNotFoundException e)
                ^
1 error
```

My question is how did the compiler know that "FileNotFoundException" will be thrown by the try block ?

Comment: Because the method (constructor) declaration tells it.

Comment: Read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167899/why-does-order-matter-when-catching-exceptions/15174337#15174337)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`catch(FileNotFoundException e)` this line is unreachable. Since:

`FileNotFoundException extends Exception`

See [Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) and [FileNotFoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html):

[image]

You probably want to switch their order.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem lies somewhere else. `FileNotFoundException` will be always caught in the `Exception` because this is a base class for all exceptions. So compiler basically complains about piece of dead code which is

```
catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File Not Found Caught");
}
```

Generally, it is not a good idea to catch `Exception`, you should always try to have more fine-grained expcetion handling, so delete this and just leave there `FileNotFoundException` block

Answer (score 4):

Your compiler can see that this exception would already be caught by the previous catch block.

When you catch `Exception`, it also catches any subclass of Exception, such as `FileNotFoundException`.

Swap the order of the catch blocks to this:

```
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) //Line 2
    {
        System.out.println("File Not Found Caught");
    }
    catch(Exception e) //Line 1
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer

*My question is how did the compiler know that "FileNotFoundException" will be thrown by the try block?*

You need to look at the constructor for `FileInputStream`

```
public FileInputStream(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this(name != null ? new File(name) : null);
}
```

Notice it `throws FileNotFoundException`. This declaration tells the compiler that a `FileNotFoundException` is possibly thrown so make sure to handle it with a `try-catch` block or let it bubble up on the method stack with another `throws` clause.

As for the error you are getting, look at all the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things at play here.

First, the compiler know that a `FileNotFoundException` could be thrown, because of the method signature of the `FileInputStream` constructor. From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html):

```
public FileInputStream(String name) throws FileNotFoundException
```

Thus, the signature tells the compiler that it could throw `FileNotFoundException`.

However, in this instance, that information is actually immaterial because of the ordering of your `catch` blocks. You have:

```
catch(Exception e) { /* ... */ }
catch(FileNotFoundException e) { /* ... */ }
```

The way `catch` blocks work, if an exception is thrown in a `try` block, execution goes through each `cacth` block and looks to see if the type of exception in the `catch` block is a polymorphic match for the thrown exception. Since `FileNotFoundException` is descended from `Exception` (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html)), it matches the first block and always will. Thus, the second block is unreachable.

So, even if the compiler did *not* know that a `FileNotFoundException` could be thrown, it could still infer that the second `catch` block is unreachable, because any `FileNotFoundException` thrown would always be caught by the first.

When defining `catch` blocks, always put them in order of most specific to least, to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change this -

```
    catch(Exception e) //Line 1
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException e) //Line 2
    {
        System.out.println("File Not Found Caught");
    }
```

to this -

```
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) //Line 1
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch(Exception e) //Line 2
    {
        System.out.println("File Not Found Caught");
    }
```

`Exception` is a super type of all the exception classes in Java. So, any exception object can be assigned to a reference of type `Exception`. When an exception occurs in your program, catch blocks are examined sequentially from top  to bottom to find a match between the type of exception occurred and the type of the exception that the `catch` block is handling. As a result, any type of exceptions generated within your try block will always find the first catch block as a match and the second catch block can never be reached from your code. This is exactly why the compiler is complaining.

Answer (score 1):

```
catch(Exception e) 
    {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
       System.out.println("File Not Found Caught");
    }
```

Exception is a super class of all the exceptions.

So if we are using catch(Exception e){} then it can catch all the type of exceptions.

So the catch(FileNotFoundExecption f){} will be not reachable, so the compiler will give an error that its already been caught.

This is the correct way to write it:

```
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
       System.out.println("File Not Found Caught");
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the point: `catch(Exception e)` will catch any `Exception`, i.e. `FileNotFoundException` too. Catching `FileNotFoundException` at a second time is thus useless.

Catch first `FileNotFoundException`, then `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

A catch block will intercept exceptions of the specified class and all its subclasses. As other mentioned `FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `Exception` and so it will be caught by the

```
catch (Exception e)
```

clause.

Answer (score 0):

[Java Virtual Machine Specification: Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.10)

> Each method in the Java Virtual Machine may be associated with zero or
>   more exception handlers. An exception handler specifies the range of
>   offsets into the Java Virtual Machine code implementing the method for
>   which the exception handler is active, describes the type of exception
>   that the exception handler is able to handle, and specifies the
>   location of the code that is to handle that exception. An exception
>   matches an exception handler if the offset of the instruction that
>   caused the exception is in the range of offsets of the exception
>   handler and the exception type is the same class as or a subclass of
>   the class of exception that the exception handler handles. When an
>   exception is thrown, the Java Virtual Machine searches for a matching
>   exception handler in the current method. If a matching exception
>   handler is found, the system branches to the exception handling code
>   specified by the matched handler.
>
> The order in which the exception handlers of a method are searched for
>   a match is important. Within a class file, the exception handlers for
>   each method are stored in a table (§4.7.3). At run time, when an
>   exception is thrown, the Java Virtual Machine searches the exception
>   handlers of the current method in the order that they appear in the
>   corresponding exception handler table in the class file, starting from
>   the beginning of that table.

If JDK compiles such code FileNotFoundException block will be unreachable. Because of exception object is checked against `instanceof`, it will always fall into first Exception block. For your case correct table will be:

```
  Exception table:
   from   to  target type
     0    18    21   Class java/io/FileNotFoundException
     0    18    33   Class java/lang/Exception
```

where `from` and `to` are instruction numbers. The table is searched top down.