# Why do we follow narrow to broad Exception catching mecahnism in java?

Tags: java

Take this piece of code:

```
try
         {
             FileReader f=new FileReader("D:/sda.t");            
         }catch(FileNotFoundException e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }catch(Exception f)
         {
             f.printStackTrace();
         }
```

1. Why do we follow this approach?
2. Why don't we just use Exception objection to catch all exceptions rather going for specific ones?

Comment: Because you want to handle each exception in a different manner, rather than handle them all the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the Catch(Exception) almost always a bad Idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416316/why-is-the-catchexception-almost-always-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Duplicate [Why does order matter when catching exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15167899/1066779)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in case of a specific exception that you are actually expecting to happen, you are going to handle it in a different way. For example, you may want to create the file when you get `FileNotFoundException`.

If you go broad to narrow as in the example you provided, then `FileNotFoundException` will never be caught, because a broader one, `Exception` is used first. So broad to narrow is useless.

Answer (score 2):

As others said, it is a bad idea to catch all `Exception`s as usually you want to handle them differently.

Though you need to also be aware that catching `Exception` also catches all `RuntimException`s, which you do generally *not* want to catch. These include things like a `NullPointerException`.

If you do not catch `RuntimeException`s then the program will just die once it reaches one and you will be notified of it, if you catch `Exception` and forget to handle anything that shows the exception, then you will miss `RuntimeException`s, which denote programmer errors.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we follow this approach?
>   Why don't we just use Exception objection to catch all exceptions rather going for specific ones?

Simple, you do this when you want to do specific tasks when a particular exception occurred.

Answer (score 1):

3 reasons:

1. To separate error handling code.
2. To be able to propagate error reporting up the call stack of methods.
3. To group and deferentiate error types.

Check out the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409563/best-practices-for-exception-management-in-java-or-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you do with the exception is printStackTrace(), then there is no/little point.  The point is different handling code can be associated with different exceptions, and matching a thrown exception against a catch list is done in the order as specified (with a first-match only selection mechanism).

Answer (score 0):

in java7 or newer you can use multicatch statement:

```
  catch(SQLException | IOException e) {
    logger.log(e);
}
```