# How it is decided which catch block comes first?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

How the catch blocks are decided in the following?

```
try{  
    int a[]=new int[5];  
    a[5]=30/0;  
}  
catch(ArithmeticException e){System.out.println("task1 is completed");}  
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){System.out.println("task 2 completed");}  
catch(Exception e){System.out.println("common task completed");}
```

I know just that derived classes come first and base classes follow them. The class `ArithmeticException` and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` come from:

```
java.lang.Exception
    java.lang.RuntimeException
        java.lang.ArithmeticException
```

and

```
java.lang.Exception
    java.lang.RuntimeException
        java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
            java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Why `ArithmeticException` is placed first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does order matter when catching exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167899/why-does-order-matter-when-catching-exceptions)

Comment: *"Why `ArithmeticException` is placed first?"* No reason. `ArithmeticException` and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` can be in either order, as long as they both are before `Exception`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're tested in the order you provide them: The first `catch` with a type that's the class of the exception being throw or a superclass of it is the one that's used. This is described in [JLS§14.20.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.1):

> - If execution of the `try` block completes abruptly because of a throw of a value V, then there is a choice:
>
>   - If the run-time type of V is assignment compatible with (§5.2) a catchable exception class of any `catch` clause of the `try` statement, then the first (leftmost) such `catch` clause is selected. The value V is assigned to the parameter of the selected `catch` clause, and the Block of that `catch` clause is executed, and then there is a choice:
>
>     - If that block completes normally, then the `try` statement completes normally.
>     - If that block completes abruptly for any reason, then the `try` statement completes abruptly for the same reason.
>   - If the run-time type of V is not assignment compatible with a catchable exception class of any `catch` clause of the try statement, then the `try` statement completes abruptly because of a throw of the value V.

Continuing with your question...

> Why `ArithmeticException` is placed first?

Because that's what the author of that code wanted to do. In that code, it doesn't matter whether the `catch` for `ArithmeticException` or `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is placed first, because they're different branches in the type hierarchy; no exception that is thrown is assignment-compatible to both of them, so it doesn't matter what order those first two `catch` blocks are in. The *third* one, though, needs to be at the end since both `ArithmeticException` and `IndexOutOfBoundsException` are assignment-compatible to `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is the first one that matches, not the "most specific one".

E.g, if you had catch(Exception e) first, the rest wouldn't even get a look in.

Comment: this one should have been a comment

Comment: Well, when I get enough reputation to actually add a comment to the original question, I will.  It's a little condescending to berate someone for not commenting when they do not have the rep to do so.  I have to provide answers that get votes first.

Comment: I dint do that. I can understand your pain! i just commented so that you could make it more elaborate and explanatory so that it would make an answer. I would up-vote if you do that!

Comment: Sorry.  It's just that I'm 2/2 being "scolded" for answering rather than commenting.

Answer (score 0):

It is a combination of order and type-matching.
The first catch block matching the type of the exception is executed.

Answer (score 0):

The ArithmetcException is not placed first in any static sense. The behaviour you observe is more to do with the evaluation of an assignment expression: In the assignment the right hand side is fully evaluated before any of the left hand side.

So the division by zero is attempted - and the relevant exception thrown - before the errant array access is even attempted.

So your code will not throw an exception pertinent to an array out of bounds access.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap the two mentioned *catch* clauses and the result will be the same.

As there is no direct hierarchical relationship between *ArithmeticException* and *ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException*, it won't matter. The exception control flows linearly from the try block.

Also, make sure the debug prints you perform have some semantics within them, not just "task 1 completed"... Ignore the above statement if this is just a test snippet and not a part of a long-run project.